# How to create a custom form validation in AMP?

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

My AMP page has a form, the form must be validated and sent by the Netlify service.
To submit a form using Netlify I add data-attribute `data-netlify="true"` and attribute  `action="amp-thank.html”` in the form tag to display the success page.
At this stage there is a problem. Google AMP requires that a script to be included on every page where there is a form, otherwise the amp page does not pass validation. `<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>`
When this script is enabled, amp also starts validating the form and conflicts with the netlify validator. How can I validate the form with the netlify service and not validate the amp?